# Missing argument 3 for wp_register_sidebar_widget()

Tags: plugins, widgets, php, sidebar, functions

I installed the Deprecated Calls plugin and it's telling me to change `register_sidebar_widget()` and `register_widget_control()`, essentially add `wp_` first.

I did but I'm getting `Missing argument 3 for wp_register_sidebar_widget()` and `wp_register_widget_control()`

Is it ok if I put the default `none` for the 3rd arg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of newer function is different:

- [`register_sidebar_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar_widget)`( $name,`**`$output_callback`**`, $classname );`
- [`wp_register_sidebar_widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget)`( $id, $name,`**`$output_callback`**`, $options );`

Can't simply replace one function with another here, need to re-order arguments accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have my function like this `wp_register_sidebar_widget('w', 'my_widget');` so I guess I'll have to add an id now.